# Finding a multiplicative identity (elementary group theory)

Tags: group-theory

for the set $[a+b\sqrt(2)| a,b \in \mathbb{Z}$] i am to check if it has a multiplicative inverse. Now I thought I was supposed to let $a_1,b_1 \in \mathbb{Z}$ and then try to find $a_2,b_2\in \mathbb{Z}$ such that:

$(a_1+b_1\sqrt(2))*(a_2+b_2\sqrt(2)) = 1$ (the identity: $a_0 =1,b_0=0$)

as all $a,b\in \mathbb{Z}$ the above equation yields two new equations:

(1) : $a_1*a_2 + 2*b_1*b_2 = 1$ and

(2) : $a_1*b_2 = -a_2*b_1$ (this is the $\sqrt(2)$-part which is 0 as the identity element is simply equal to 1)

and then isolate a term and substitute one equation into the other. But that just got messy and I didn't really see how to either find and identity element or disprove that an identity element exists.

How to proceed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Your set of numbers is a subset (more precisely a sub-ring) of $\mathbb{R}$. So for the inverse, you can simply take the inverse in $\mathbb{R}$ and check that this is again in your ring.
2. The general formula is $$(a+b\sqrt{2})^{-1}=\frac{a-b\sqrt{2}}{a^2-2b^2}$$
3. In your subring, not every element is invertible. For example the inverse of $5$ would be $1/5$, which is not in your ring.